# Perl: How to split paragraph keeping last sentences into another array?

Tags: regex, perl, xml-parsing, xml-twig

I am trying to split `<Description>` text by `Bit` *number* and to put into particular `Bit` *number* element. Here is the file, I am parsing.

```
        <Register>
                <Name>abc</Name>
                <Abstract></Abstract>
                <Description>Bit 6  random description
                    Bit 5 msg octet 2
                    Bit 4-1 
                    Bit 0 msg octet 4
                    These registers containpart of the Upstream Message. 
                    They should be written only after the cleared by hardware.
                    </Description>
        <Field>
        <Name>qwe</Name>

        <Description></Description>
        <BitFieldOffset>6</BitFieldOffset>
        <Size>1</Size>
        <AccessMode>Read/Write</AccessMode>

        </Field>
    <Field>
        <Name>qwe</Name>

        <Description></Description>
        <BitFieldOffset>5</BitFieldOffset>
        <Size>1</Size>
        <AccessMode>Read/Write</AccessMode>

        </Field>
<Field>
....
</Field>
                </Register>
            <Register>
                <Name>xyz</Name>
                <Abstract></Abstract>
                <Description>Bit 3  msg octet 1
                    Bit 2 msg octet 2
                    Bit 1 msg octet 3
                    Bit 0 msg octet 4
                    These registers. 
                    They should be written only after the cleared by hardware.
                </Description>
<Field>
....
</Field>
<Field>
....
</Field>
            </Register>
```

The expected output would be:

```
Expected output:

<Register>
<long_description>
These registers containpart of the Upstream Message. 
    They should be written only after the cleared by hardware.
</long_description>

<bit_field position="6" width=" 1">
<long_description>
<p> random description</p>
</long_description>
<bit_field position="5" width=" 1">
<long_description>
<p>...</p>
</long_description>
<bit_field position="1" width=" 4">
<long_description>
<p>...</p>
</long_description>

</Register>

<Register>
.
.
.
</Register>
```

I am using XML-Twig package to parse this file but got stuck into the splitting.

```
foreach my $register ( $twig->get_xpath('//Register') ) # get each <Register>
    {

        my $reg_description= $register->first_child('Description')->text;
        .
        .
        .
          foreach my $xml_field ($register->get_xpath('Field'))
          {
             .
             .
             my @matched = split ('Bit\s+[0-9]', $reg_description);
             .
             .
           }
   }
```

I do not know how to create `<bit_field>` accordingly and keep text except `Bit` into `<Register> <long_description>`. Can anyone please help here?

**Edits**:
The `Bit` in `<Description>` can have multiple lines. e.g in following example, `Bit 10-9`'s description is till starting of `Bit 8`

```
<Description>Bit 11 GOOF 
Bit 10-9 Clk Selection:
 00 :  8 MHz
 01 :  4 MHz
 10 :  2 MHz
 11 :  1 MHz
Bit 8 Clk Enable : 1 = Enable CLK
<Description>
```

Comment: Did you write that XML example in Word? There are ellipsis characters in it... :)

Comment: Can you please [edit] and provide an [mcve] that we can copy and run?

Comment: Yes. I copied the example into Word and modified to just show where I got stuck :)

Comment: Sorry, I might have not made myself clear. I'd appreciate a full example program that's reduced to only the problem at hand, but includes the parsing to reproduce the problem. Like, stick the XML in a `__DATA__` section, do the reading and parsing, so that it's easy to take that scaffold and add code.

Comment: I have edited the example. Can you please see if it works?

Comment: Is the format of that text always the same? One line per bit, and the lines without bits are the overall long description?

Comment: One/multiple lines per bit. And yes, the lines without bits are the overall long description.

Comment: Where does `width` come from? And what's with `Bit 4-1`? Can you describe the format of these entries more clearly?

Comment: Width comes from <Field><Size>. Or if it's `Bit 5`, the width is 1. If it's `Bit 4-1`, it's for Bit 4,3,2,1 and the width is 4.

Comment: Please never let your code or data anywhere near document editors like Word or PDFEdit. You need to use a simple text editor such as Notepad.

Comment: As the description of a bit can continue on subsequent lines, how can one determine if lines following the last bit belong to the description of this last bit or are part of the overall description of the register?

Comment: That's how the owner created it. I agree with you @sticky bit, it can be possible. But in my files, there are no such cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got everything right, you could look at the whole text block line by line.

Use a regular expression, to check if a line matches the pattern for a bit. Capture the relevant parts. Cache bit by bit in an array holding hashes storing the details of each bit.

Buffer lines that don't contain the bit pattern. If another line follows, that contains a bit pattern, the buffer must belong to the recent bit. Append it there. All other lines must be part of the overall description. **Note:** This doesn't distinguish between any additional lines of the description for the last bit. If there is such a bit, its additional lines will make the beginning of the overall description. (But you said such things aren't in your data.)

Proof of concept:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $description_in = 'Bit 6  random description
                    Bla bla additional line bla bla
                    bla bla
                    Bit 5 msg octet 2
                    Empty line below

                    Bla bla set to gain instant world domination bla bla
                    Bit 4-1
                    Bit 0 msg octet 4
                    These registers containpart of the Upstream Message.
                    They should be written only after the cleared by hardware.

                    Empty line above
                    Bla bla bla...';

my @bits = ();
my $description_overall = '';

my $line_buffer = '';
foreach my $line (split("\n", $description_in)) {
  # if line
  #  begins with optional white spaces
  #  followed by "Bit"
  #  followed by at least one white space
  #  followed by at least one digit (we capture the digits)
  #  followed by an optional sequence of optional white spaces, "-", optional white spaces and at least one digit (we capture the digits)
  #  followed by an optional sequence of at least one white space and any characters (we capture the characters)
  #  followed by the end of the line
  if ($line =~ m/^\s*Bit\s+(\d+)(?:\s*-\s*(\d+))?(?:\s+(.*?))?$/) {
    my ($position_begin, $position_end, $description) = ($1, $2, $3);
    my $width;

    # if there already are bits we've processed
    if (scalar(@bits)) {
      # the lines possibly buffered belong to the bit before the current one, so append them to its description
      $bits[$#bits]->{description} .= (length($bits[$#bits]->{description}) ? "\n" : '') . $line_buffer;
      # and reset the line buffer to collect the additional lines of the current bit;
      $line_buffer = '';
    }

    # $position_end is defined only if it was a "Bit n-m"
    # otherwise set it to $position_begin
    $position_end = defined($position_end) ? $position_end : $position_begin;

    $width = abs($position_end - $position_begin) + 1;

    # set description to the empty string if not defined (i.e. no description was found)
    $description = defined($description) ? $description : '';

    # push a ref to a new hash with the keys position, description and width into the list of bits
    push(@bits, { position => (sort({$a <=> $b} ($position_begin, $position_end)))[0], # always take the lower position
                  description => $description,
                  width => $width });
  }
  else {
    # it's not a bit pattern, so just buffer the line
    $line_buffer .= (length($line_buffer) ? "\n" : '') . $line;
  }
}
# anything still in the buffer must belong to the overall description
$description_overall .= $line_buffer;

print("<Register>\n  <long_description>\n$description_overall\n  </long_description>\n");
foreach my $bit (@bits) {
  print("  <bit_field position=\"$bit->{position}\" width=\"$bit->{width}\">\n    <long_description>\n$bit->{description}\n    </long_description>\n  </bit_field>\n")
}
print("</Register>\n");
```

Prints:

```
<Register>
  <long_description>
                        These registers containpart of the Upstream Message.
                        They should be written only after the cleared by hardware.

                        Empty line above
                        Bla bla bla...
  </long_description>
  <bit_field position="6" width="1">
    <long_description>
random description
                        Bla bla additional line bla bla
                        bla bla
    </long_description>
  </bit_field>
  <bit_field position="5" width="1">
    <long_description>
msg octet 2
                        Empty line below

                        Bla bla set to gain instant world domination bla bla
    </long_description>
  </bit_field>
  <bit_field position="1" width="4">
    <long_description>

    </long_description>
  </bit_field>
  <bit_field position="0" width="1">
    <long_description>
msg octet 4
    </long_description>
  </bit_field>
</Register>
```

I wrote it as stand alone script, so that I could test it. You'll have to adapt it into your script.

Maybe add some processing of the overall description eliminating those long sequences of white spaces.

First I tried using a continuing pattern (`while ($x =~ m/^...$/gc)`) but that somehow ate the line endings away resulting in only matching every second line. Lookarounds, to keep them out of the actual match, didn't work (said it wasn't implemented; I guess, I'll have to check my Perl on this computer?), so the explicit splitting into lines is a work around.

It might also be possible to shorten it using `grep()`s, `map()`s or the like. But the verbose version better demonstrates the ideas, I think. So I didn't even look into that.

Comment: Many thanks @sticky bit. This works for me except Bit _number_ has multiple lines in `$description_in`.

Comment: @Nee: Sorry I don't really understand what that means. Can you explain the format in greater detail regarding your comment in an edit of the question? May then I'll get this.

Comment: Please see 'Edits' at the end of the question.